# How to set base path property in swagger for .Net Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, swashbuckle

i've built a Web API in ASP.Net Core (version 1.1.2) and i use the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore for generating the swagger definition.

below is a part of the automatically generated swagger definition. i would like to change the paths so it does not include **/api/ApiName** but it would be included in the **basePath** which is now **/**

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "ApiName.V1"
    },
    "host": "ApiUrl",
    "basePath": "/api/ApiName",
    "paths": {
        "/": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "ApiName"
                ],
                .........
```

so what i would like to get is:

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "v1",
        "title": "ApiName.V1"
    },
    "host": "ApiUrl",
    "basePath": "/",
    "paths": {
        "/api/ApiName": {
            "get": {
                "tags": [
                    "ApiName"
                ],
                .........
```

We have some other APIs which are not written in .Net Core and there it fixed the same issue by adding default routes. I tried to do the same on .Net core by removing the route at the top of the API controller

```
[Route("api/[Controller]")]
```

and adding it to the Startup.cs. however this did not work. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in the end i used this to fix it:

you can set the PreSerializeFilters to add both the BasePath and edit the Paths. Thought there would be a more elegant way but this works.

```
var basepath = "/api/AppStatus";
c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = basepath);


c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => {
    IDictionary<string, PathItem> paths = new Dictionary<string, PathItem>();
    foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
    {
        paths.Add(path.Key.Replace(basepath, "/"), path.Value);
    }
    swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't compile for me - this worked
`
            app.UseSwagger(options =>
            {
                var basepath = "/api-base-path";

                options.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
                {
                    var paths = new OpenApiPaths();
                    foreach (var path in swaggerDoc.Paths)
                    {
                        paths.Add($"{basepath}{path.Key}", path.Value);
                    }
                    swaggerDoc.Paths = paths;
                });
            });
`

Answer (score 27):

BasePath was used in [Swagger v2.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/api-host-and-base-path/)
It has been replaced by the servers array in [OpenApi v3.0](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/api-host-and-base-path/)

In v5 you have to do this for using OpenApi v3.0:

```
var basePath = "/v1";
app.UseSwagger(c =>
    {
        c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
        c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
        {
            swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer> { new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}{basePath}" } };
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an **IDocumentFilter** with that you can modify the result swagger definition.
 I have some examples here:

https://github.com/heldersepu/SwashbuckleTest/blob/master/Swagger_Test/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L285