# How can I stop Swashbuckle adding an unwanted (and unspecified) Base URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have an odd problem where my API project has started inserting a base URL ("/swagger") seemingly overnight with no changes to the code. The base URL only appears when I am working on the project locally, when it is deployed to an Azure app service everything is normal. See image for the problem:

[image]

In startup my swagger setup looks like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "My AppName API", Version = "v1" });
        c.OperationFilter<SwaggerTokenParameter>();
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ...

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
    });

    ...            
}
```

I have tried recloning the project onto my machine but the problem has persisted, I have also tried manually setting the `RoutePrefix`:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("../swagger/v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");
    c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
}
```

This doesn't help - it just breaks the UI and the definition still contains the base url:

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"version":"v1","title":"My AppName API"},"basePath":"/swagger",...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set base path property in swagger for .Net Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327119/how-to-set-base-path-property-in-swagger-for-net-core-web-api)

Comment: @Helen Thank you so much for finding that question, I had been looking for something like that for weeks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45370154/8532748) I was able to come up with a solution. I still don't understand what changed to add in the base URL though or why it doesn't happen in the App Service.

```
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) =>
    {
        swaggerDoc.BasePath = null;
    });
});
```