# Swagger: change api route in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-aks

I have two kubernetes services deployed on a AKS, they receive traffic from a Nginx Ingress Controller. The endpoints for these two services are `https:<dns>/service1`and `https:<dns>/service2`. Now I want to set up Swagger for each services. Below is how I set up Swagger UI for one of the services.

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/service1/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
        });
```

With this configuration, I can get access to swagger by `https:<dns>/service1/swagger`.

Now the problem is, in Swagger UI, when I want to test the api by clicking the "Try it out" button then Excute button, the url that Swagger UI access is  `https:<dns>/api/v1/contoller` instead of `https:<dns>/service1/api/v1/contoller`. Which means that Swagger UI is not aware of the existance of path `/service1/`. I found several related questions like this one [How to change base url of Swagger in ASP.NET core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116047/how-to-change-base-url-of-swagger-in-asp-net-core)
. But they are not the solution for my problem. My guess is I need to set a base path for Swagger. If anyone could tell me how to configure base path for Swagger in ASP.NET core 2.0, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure something out? Having the same problem and no luck.

Comment: @ecramer Unfortunately, no. This should be a common problem when using swagger behind Ingress, but I cannot find any post or article mentions it.

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327119/how-to-set-base-path-property-in-swagger-for-net-core-web-api. not necessarily the prettiest solution however it has worked for us

Comment: @ecramer Indeed it works for me as well, thank you so much for letting me know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change this:

```cs
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("/service1/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
});
```

to this:

**For dotnet core 2.x**

```cs
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
#if !DEBUG
  c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.BasePath = "/service1");
#endif
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
});
```

**For dotnet core 3.x** *(Swashbuckle 5.x prerelease+)*

```cs
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
#if !DEBUG
  c.RouteTemplate = "swagger/{documentName}/swagger.json";
  c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.Servers = new System.Collections.Generic.List<OpenApiServer>
  {
    new OpenApiServer { Url = $"{httpReq.Scheme}://{httpReq.Host.Value}/service1" }
  });
#endif
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
  c.SwaggerEndpoint("./swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API V1");
});
```

**#if !DEBUG** ... **#endif** is necessary for accessing the swagger ui while debugging in local machine.

**Note:** I'm assuming "/service1" is the same value as in your values.yaml file of your helm chart. *(see below)*

```yaml
...
ingress:
  enabled: true
  annotations: {
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx",
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  }
  path: /service1/?(.*)
  hosts:
    - your-aks-subdomain.your-azure-region.cloudapp.azure.com
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

hpa:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Please en your `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {`

use after this:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c=>
              {
                   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/service1/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Giftaway API V1");
```

This option

```
c.RoutePrefix = "service1";
```

this will get you `https:<dns>/service1/api/v1/controller`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The "RoutePrefix" option is actually used to change swagger endpoint. In my case, if it is not set, the swagger UI can be accessed by `https:<dns>/service1/swagger`, if I set the option `c.RoutePrefix = "service1";` then I can access the swagger UI by `https:<dns>/service1/service1`

Comment: It doesn't. Changing swagger access name is not what I want

Comment: When you mean that tha url changes to service1/service1 you mean when you are accessing to swagger.json? If this is the case you need to change `c.SwaggerEndpoint("/service1/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Giftaway API V1");` to `c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Giftaway API V1");`. You need to specify only the base route on `c.RoutePrefix = "service1";` and this route will work for every enpoint. In case you need it in service url, you need to add it on `Route("api/{Controller}")]` in your controllers or use sa middleware to add the path to the base route.

Comment: Thanks! Your .NET core 3 example works in .NET 6, Swashbuckle 6.5, OpenApi 3, but I removed the `c.RouteTemplate` line because that is the same as the default value now.

Comment: Good, please provide the example as an update fro this issue! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools/issues/342#issuecomment-391940961 and https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/1217 maybe you could try setting the X-forwarded-prefix in your ingress rule like https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/pull/1805#issuecomment-366896998

Answer (score 0):

In your ingress don't use  this annotation

nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /

Answer (score 0):

I am using ASP.NET Core 6 with Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 6.5 and UNOPARATOR required changes for it to work:

```cs
        app.UseSwagger(c =>
        {
#if !DEBUG

            c.PreSerializeFilters.Add((swaggerDoc, httpReq) => swaggerDoc.Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>
            {
                // {httpReq.Scheme} is http on deployed version, so hardcoding https
                new OpenApiServer { Url = $"https://{httpReq.Host.Value}/serviceName" }
            });
#endif
        });
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
```

What I do not understand is why `httpReq.Scheme` returned `http` when deployed, but I have `https` everywhere, so I can safely hardcoded (not happy with this though).