# ASP Core generate full paths for all endpoints

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes

I need to retrieve all endpoints in an ASP Core application and generate their full paths.

example: `/a/b/c/endpoint`, `x/y/endpoint`,...

Those endpoints need to include controller actions as well as endpoints that are manually defined in `StartUp` using the `Map*()` methods.

I am able to retrieve a list of endpoints using:

```
services.GetRequiredService<EndpointDataSource>().Endpoints;
```

But I can't find a way how to create a corresponding full path for an `Endpoint`, especially if that endpoint is within a branched ASP pipeline. The Endpoint objects have a `RoutePattern` property that can be used but we still need the base path of the branched pipeline(s).

Cheers

Comment: Don't you get all that through Swagger?

Comment: Can't really depend on other libraries with this one. I assumed there must be some way ASP can generate that route.

Comment: Swagger/OpenAPI is the endpoint specification standard, not some other library. Some ASP.NET Core web app templates (eg webapi) include support by default, so that's the built-in way you're looking for. Have you tried using it?

Comment: OpenAPI [also works with minimal APIs since ASP.NET Core 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-6/#configure-swagger-ui-with-minimal-apis)

Comment: As for `Can't really depend on other libraries with this one.` you can't use .NET Core at all without third-party libraries. Even .NET Framework 4.x depended heavily on third party libraries (eg Json.NET) and NuGet packages. This isn't a `yes but the customer`.  If the customer doesn't want third party libraries in 2021 they don't want *any* application. All languages (C#, Python, Javascript, Java, even C++) depend on external packages for anything beyond non-trivial console apps. In fact, you already have to use external libraries, eg for file logging

Comment: Thx. I guess I still would need to include the Swagger/OpenAPI related NuGet packages? I can dig through their source code to see how they do it (assuming swagger includes the ones defined with `Map*` within the `UseEndpoints` middleware configurer)

Comment: What's the real question here? Why do you insist on not using libraries? You have to do that just to log to files - ASP.NET Core doesn't include a file logger *on purpose*. As for copying that code- what's the point?

Comment: When I say `other libraries` I mean anything that is outside the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK.

Comment: Again, why? That makes no sense and besides **you already use other libraries**. You can't not use other libraries in any modern language

Comment: Seriously, this question can't be answered as is. Saying you don't want to use other libraries without an explanation means you don't want to use .NET Core, period. And most likely, there's no real reason for this. At best, management or customers misunderstood how web development works. They'll have to overcome this

Comment: The `Map` methods create a new middleware pipeline, manipulating `.PathBase` before the next hander (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/afda412c0f283b809979a3321ebbac053ba45d06/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapMiddleware.cs#L67). That's probably impossible to handle in a generic way. Are you using `.UseEndpoints()` in multiple pipelines?

Comment: PS: other third party libraries you already depend on - Bootstrap,.JQuery, JQuery Validation etc. MVC and Razor Pages uses Bootstrap and JQuery

Comment: It's a library and that makes that requirement. I can not use anything besides the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` SDK. Swagger Nuget is something outside `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, but I'll check the Swagger source code. Thx for the tip.

Regarding the question, it simply states, `Can I create full paths for all endpoints using ASP Core APIs?`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thx : )  yes there are multiple pipelines with `UseEndpoints`. As you are asking I guess you already know the problem, as we cannot just take the basepath when generating the routes as that basepath corresponds to the pipeline the code is running at : )

Comment: @nod even more reason to *NOT* do this yourself. It's not the library's job to generate those paths, it's the application's. It's the application that has to host the Swagger endpoint after all. And the application would prefer 1000 times over to use a *standardized* method for this instead of your own custom method. The attributes that either NSwagger or Swashbuckle use like `ProducesResponseType` or `ApiController` are part of ASP.NET Core itself

Comment: @nod `yes there are multiple pipelines` so the real problem is how to get whatever the application is using to detect your endpoints, not implement your API that will almost certainly conflict with the application. Swagger allows setting a BasePath. Check  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327119/how-to-set-base-path-property-in-swagger-for-net-core-web-api). Swagger UI can combine multiple APIs too, as [Combining multiple Swagger API endpoints in a single UI](https://dejanstojanovic.net/aspnet/2020/april/combining-multiple-swagger-api-endpoints-in-a-single-ui/) shows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I really appreciate your time, but I just cannot use Swagger, Bootstrap, etc.. whatever is outside `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`. 
Btw, I just tested and Swagger does not pick up all endpoint as well. It just picks those defined as Controller actions.
I also do not need any swagger Ui or similar, I just need an endpoint that can report back all endpoints including the ones defined in `UseEndpoints` at `StartUp`. If it's not possible I'm ok with that and will move on :) The `EndpointDataSource` does pick up all of them, from all pipelines, but just cant generate full paths :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paraphrasing your question, you have a branching request pipeline, calling `.UseEndpoints` in multiple branches. But while the `.Map` middleware adjusts `Request.Path` & `Request.PathBase`, end point routing is oblivious to this change.

I don't think this is supported in link generation. You should probably take a step back and re-evaluate if you really need to use `.Map` at all. Or at least the `preserveMatchedPathSegment = true` overload.

After a quick peek into the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore).

The [`.Map`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/88c720f125a92df225dccc4a6308a865e179e37d/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/MapExtensions.cs#L50) methods each create a separate `IApplicationBuilder` for that branched middleware pipeline.

Calling [`.UseRouting()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/88c720f125a92df225dccc4a6308a865e179e37d/src/Http/Routing/src/Builder/EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L39) creates an `IEndpointRouteBuilder`.

The `IEndpointRouteBuilder` is then used by [`.UseEndpoints()`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/Builder/EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs#L103) to define all the endpoints.

So here's a quick outline of what I'd attempt.

Write your own extension methods to replace `.Map` & `.UseEndpoints` and use those in your `Startup` class.

Store (or combine) the new path base in `IApplicationBuilder.Properties`.

Then in your `.UseEndpoints()` callback, you can call the real one. Then create your own datasource with [`EndpointDataSource src = new CompositeEndpointDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder.DataSources)`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/88c720f125a92df225dccc4a6308a865e179e37d/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs#L44). Combine that with the path base you stored earlier.

And populate all that into some other service object for later use.

Unless someone can point out a simpler way?

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look. Looking at the source code for ASP's `LinkGenerator` (DefaultLinkGenerator) where they use Endpoints internally, they seem to be taking the `HttpRequest.PathBase` by default in case the user does not provide it explicitly, which implies that it may not work for routes in different pipelines (I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: Btw this might actually work in case you have full control over the application and are able to use the custom extension methods. In the case of a custom middleware library it seems we are out of luck, but I'll dig more through the source code.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it gives a possible solution for the question asked. I am creating a middleware library where it's problematic to support replacements for Map and UseEndpoints as it's supposed to be plugged into the pipeline without further modifications, but the answer is valid for the question which does not specify a middleware library requirement.

Comment: It's a pity, but that's just how it has always worked. eg https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10612

Comment: You could also explore replacing the `IApplicationBuilderFactory` service to inspect the map, routing and endpoint middleware in `.Use` / `.New`. But that seems a bit heavy handed.